# How to change the name of the file taken as input by a function

Tags: c++, file, char

I have this function in C++:

```
void file_to_vect(double * a, char * name_file);
```

that takes in input a vector and writes it on the file whose name is specified by name_file. The problem is that I want to use this function on a file whose name changes. For example

```
file_to_vect(a,"file_18.txt")
```

Where the number after "file_" is not fixed. I've tried to do that by:

```
int n=18;
file_to_vect(a,"file_"+char(n)+".txt");
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::ostringstream`, `std::string`, and/or `std::to_string`?

Comment: your question is: How to concatenate strings?